# Searching for numbers, doing arithmetic on results, then replacing

Tags: javascript

I need to search and replace numbers in a string. However there are two caveats.

First, I need to do arithmetic before replacing. So if I was adding 5 to them, a search for 6 would replace it with 11, 7 with 12, etc.

Second, I'm only doing numbers that are followed by a colon. So '7:' would become '12:', '8:' would become '13:', but just '9' with no colon would remain unchanged.

Here is something I've tried

```
var string = "89 12 13: 42:"; 
var regex = new RegExp('[0-9]+','g');
string = string.replace(regex + ':',(regex + 5) + ':');
```

It should look like "89 12 18: 47:" when finished. The plus 5 means I'm trying to add 5 to the number that comes out before replacing.

Thanks,

Comment: Stackoverflow.com isn't a free code writing services (against the wishes of many...). Best to post what you have tried and then come here to get help.

Comment: I don't have a problem understanding the regex, the problem is what I'm replacing with depends on the thing I'm replacing

Comment: Give some example input/output. Show at least 2 examples of a string, and then the same string after modifying numbers. Lastly, show the code you are currently working on and ask a more specific question about the line(s) of code not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close; but you're not scanning for `:` and you're missing `.replace` with a function.

```js
test = "I like 55: 12: 9: yay";

test = test.replace(/[0-9]+:/g, function (a) {
  return Number(a.slice(0,-1)) + 5 + ":";
});
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Your solution worked. However I don't understand how the function that's being passed knows to take the search result as its own argument. Is this just default behavior?

Comment: It's taking the entire capture, and then it removes the `:`, converts it then re appends it. It's the function's default behaviour